# Designing WCF interface: no out or ref parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WCF service and web client. Web service implements one method SubmitOrders.
This method takes a collection of orders. The problem is that service must return an array
of results for each order - true or false. Marking WCF paramters as out or ref makes no
sense. What would you recommend?

```
[ServiceContact]
public bool SubmitOrders(OrdersInfo)

[DataContract]
public class OrdersInfo
{
  Order[] Orders;
}
```

Comment: OK. This was just my lack of knowledge on WCF attributes. Thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Marking WCF paramters as out or ref makes no sense.

out parameters do make sense in WCF.

> What would you recommend?

I recommend to use out parameters.

---

Note 1: It will move your out parameter to be the first parameter on you.

Note 2: Yes you can return objects with complex types in WCF.  Tag your class with an attribute of [DataContract] and your properties with an attribute of [DataMember].

Comment: I agree, we've used them extensively in our own services. 

You could also mark the method as IsOneWay=False and pass back an array of whatever data you want to the caller rather than just a bool.

Comment: Err.. I see. I thought that WCF serializes the class into messages
and the message is transfered to service. Out parameters assume some
back message to client - am i right?

Comment: Just don't add the OneWayAttribute! The default is Request/Response.

Comment: Why out parameter should move to the first place ? Now I get error and WCF auto moves out to the first place. Is it a rule of WCF ?
Thx.

Comment: I believe i can't use out parameters when using `webHttpBinding`. Can I?

Answer (score 3):

Use complex type(another class with DataContract attribute) in return.

Like

```
[ServiceContact]
public OrdersResult SubmitOrders(OrdersInfo)

[DataContract]
public class OrdersInfo
{
  Order[] Orders;
}

[DataContract]
public class OrdersResult
{
  .....
}
```

Also add `DataMember` on `Order[] Orders;`

Comment: It's not needed to create another DataContract obj. Just pass as out parameter.

Comment: Both solutions will work. It depends from designed whether he wants to have out param or return complex type.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to avoid out and ref parameters, you could always return an array of the IDs of the orders that were successfully submitted.

Comment: @Captain: I'm not sure about WCF specifically, but SOAP services can use "out" parameters.  I would guess WCF supports that since it makes sense at least with SOAP and TCP/IP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes sense returning an **out parameter** on WCF operations. On response, the SOAP message will contain the element passed back.

There are good content on MSDN about data transfer: [Specifying Data Transfer in Service Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732038%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Also, you need to use the **OperationContractAttribute** (not ServiceContractAttribute) on the SubmitOrders.

Comment: Thank you. This is just a typo This was not copypaste, I just simplified the problem and typed code in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Special class that holds the order and the true/false, or an array of tupels.

Answer (score 1):

The method would look like:

```
public OrdersInfo SubmitOrders(OrderInfo orders){
}
```

where each item in the OrderInfo will have a SubmissionStatusInfo like:

```
class SubmissionStatusInfo{
 enum Status  { get; set; }
 string Message { get; set; }
}
```

where `Status : Submitted, Failed, Error` etc.
`Message` : a string giving some additional information about the status...

HTH

Comment: You can perform FaultException<SubmissionStatusInfo>. It's a "best practice" on passing back an error.