# WCF: operations with out parameters are not supported

Tags: .net, rest, wcf

I've created a simple WCF service inside of WebApplication project.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://my.domain.com/service")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public string PublishProfile(out string enrollmentId, string registrationCode)
    {
        enrollmentId = null;
        return "Not supported";
    }
```

built - everything is compiled successfully

After that I've tried to open service in browser, I've got the following error:

> Operation 'PublishProfile' in contract 'MyService' specifies an 'out' or 'ref' parameter. Operations with 'out' or 'ref' parameters are not supported

Can't I use 'out' parameters?

What is wrong here?

Thanks

P.S. I use VS2008 SP1, .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in my case was that default service configuration created in my ASP.NET application with Visual Studio wizard was a service type. Endpoint binding was "webHttpBinding". As far as I understand now it is binding for REST services, and they just don't have physical ability to work with out parameters. For them out parameter is not supported. And what I actually needed was a 'basicHttpBinding" that allows to work with out parameters.

Many thanks to everybody who helped me to figure out that.

Comment: Yee,,, I didn't mention that I am using REST service. But actually, I didn't know that myself.

Answer (score 2):

The answer I've found was:

"The idea of an out parameter is that the method will instantiate the null reference that you pass in. A web service is stateless; therefore the handle that you have on an object that goes into a webservice as a parameter will not be the same as the one that makes it into the webservice server side. The nature of this prevents out parameters."

[Source](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/11859/38066.aspx)

Comment: On my experience I've used 'out' parameters (in another project). Idea from another link (see schellack's answer) suggests: out parameters do make sense in WCF, I recommend to use out parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public string PublishProfile(out string enrollmentId, string registrationCode)
...
```

I believe the default body style (bare) only supports a single return value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Out` parameter should come after.

it should be like this:

```
public string PublishProfile(string registrationCode, out string enrollmentId)
```

Also, you are setting the string to `null` - why not use `string.Empty`?

Comment: That is a stub only... But probably I need to know more why string.Empty is better

Comment: changing position for 'outed' parameter doesn't help.

Comment: http://codeasp.net/forums/asp-net-topics/getting-started-general-asp-net/117/what-is-difference-between-null-vs-string-empty-vsin-c has a good answer regarding `string.empty`. Regarding your original question, I am actually stumped why you are getting an error...

Comment: I just created a Sample asp.net project and added a WCF project and tested this, but I can not recreate this error. Is it possible to post a sample? I tried it in VS2010 for .NET 3.5 framework

Comment: here are couple of link to further look into: http://dhamijadinesh.wordpress.com/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See [Designing WCF interface: no out or ref parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882178/designing-wcf-interface-no-out-or-ref-parameters)

Comment: So? Those link DO suggest to use 'out' parameters. I saw it, but see nothing related to current issue. Could you please clarify?